# Reference request for a paper with Vanishing viscosity method and smooth approximation of initial data

Tags: reference-request, parabolic-pde, hyperbolic-pde, conservation-laws

I am trying to find the papers/books/notes that study problem (1),(3) given bellow using the vanishing viscosity method. I am especially interested in solutions in Sobolev spaces.

**More detailed explanation:**

From Chapter 10 of "Hyperbolic partial differential equations", P. Lax, 2006:

The vanishing viscosity method for solving the initial value problem for hyperbolic systems of conservation laws consists of finding solutions of
    $$(1) \hspace{1cm}    
 u_t+A(u)\cdot u_x  = 0,
 \hspace{1cm} A_{ij}=\frac{\partial{f_i}}{\partial{u_j}},
 \hspace{1cm}
 u(x,0)=u_{0}(x),\\[2ex] 
 $$
    as the limit of solutions of the parabolic system
    $$(2) \hspace{1cm}    
 u_t+A(u)\cdot u_x  = \epsilon u_{xx},\\[2ex] 
 $$
    when $\epsilon\rightarrow0.$

In literature, when solving problem $(2)$, we use the same initial data $u_0$, if they are smooth enough. Otherwise, if they are not smooth enough, we take smooth enough version $u_0^{\epsilon}$ (of course here it could be some other paramether instead of $\epsilon$, but let's not complicate this more than it needs to be).

Riemann initial data are given with:

$$(3) \hspace{1cm}
u(x,0)= \begin{cases}
u_l, x<0 \\[2ex]
u_r, x\geq 0.
\end{cases}$$

**I am interested in** papers where the authors used this technique:

1. First they transform the initial data $(3)$ to the smooth one $u_0^{\epsilon}$ (this can be done for example by convolution of Riemann data $(3)$ with a mollifier).
2. Than they solve the problem $(2)$ with the smooth data $u_0^{\epsilon}$ using the vanishing viscosity method.
3. At the end they connect that solution to the solution of the original problem $(1), (3)$ by letting $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

The papers that I've found and that satisfy this conditions are given bellow (but none of them has solutions in the Sobolev spaces):

1.["Global Solutions of the Navier-Stokes Equations for Multidimensional Compressible Flow with Discontinuous Initial Data" - D. Hoff, 1995](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022039685711114)

2.["Vanishing viscosity solutions of nonlinear hyperbolic systems" - S. Bianchini, A. Bressan, 2005](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v161-n1-p06.pdf)

3.["On the uniqueness of vanishing viscosity solutions for Riemann problems for polymer flooding" - W. Shen, 2017](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs00030-017-0461-y.pdf)

Help with this would be nice (there are just too much references in the literature that use the vanishing viscosity method and I can't read them all).